# How to stop Google Cast excessive logging on Android?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Google Cast is logging to logcat like crazy on all my devices. The log is full of annoying garbage like:

```
I/CastMediaRouteProvider: Published ...
I/Publisher: Processing device ...
I/CastDeviceController: ...
```

which makes development very tedious process. Is there any way to shut it off?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something like `^((?!CastMediaRouteProvider|Publisher|CastDeviceController).)*$` in my logcat filter but would be awesome to turn it off completely.